# How to retrieve Version Number and Install Date of a specific Installed Package?

Tags: package

I'm building a VF page which will display information of the following details:
Version Number of Installed Package - I got from Publisher Object (merging MajorVersion and MinorVersion gives the Version Number of currently Managed Package)

The more important thing is how to get:
'Install Date' of a specific Installed Package

Does someone have an idea how to perform this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object name is `PackageLicense`.

`CreatedDate` is the Install Date.

I don't think Version Number is exposed on this object yet.

```
SELECT CreatedDate FROM PackageLicense WHERE NamespacePrefix = 'ABC'
```